# Radio button with label align vertical

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to build a radio button, in this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/radio-button-gx1ry), I am not able to properly make the vertical align of the label, I think it's because I am missing something on the absolute and relative part, tried vertical align also but didn't work.

Is there a better way of doing it with flex?

If I use flex I am not able to properly assign the small round inside the input.

Comment: You want the label to be positioned on the right side of the radio circle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to position the label on the right side of the radio button.

It looks like you're trying to use flexbox, so i'll answer using it.

First, you should place label after the radio button in `RadioButton` :

```
return (
  <Label htmlFor={id} disabled={disabled}>
    <Input
      id={id}
      type="radio"
      role="radio"
      name={name}
      value={value}
      disabled={disabled}
      onChange={onChange}
      checked={checked}
    />
    <Indicator />
    {label} // <----
  </Label>
);
```

Then, you can use flexbox for `Label` :

```
const Label = styled.label`
  display: flex;       // <----
  align-items: center; // <----
  cursor: ${({ disabled }) => (disabled ? "not-allowed" : "pointer")};
  font-size: 24px;
`;
```

Finally, you need to make `Indicator` position relative :

```
const Indicator = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.75em;
  position: relative; // <---

  ${Label}:hover & {
    background: #ccc;
  }
```

Comment: This worked for me and thanks for the explanation and step by step approach, just one doubt since the font-size is 24px it will take label and radio button will increase the size how can i reduce the size for label text, basically two sizes for text and radio button